# Does a 'ConcatDataset' in pytorch iterates each Datasets ununiformly?

Tags: pytorch

I have two custom Dataset, and use ConcatDataset for concat these Dataset during training.
and I use this code for concat
`dataset = ConcatDataset([CustomDataset1,CustomDataset2])`

and this ConcatDataset pick each dataset one by one uniformly.
but I want to pick each dataset un-uniformly

ex. CustomDataset1, CustomDataset1, CustomDataset2, CustomDataset1, CustomDataset1, CustomDataset2 ...

How can I that???